# How to check if somebody else editing same entity

Tags: mysql, concurrency

Lets say in admin panel one user editing any entity lets say product is there a way if another user who also if try to edit the same entity/product info would able to get a notification or something that "somebody else already editing the same so ask him to wait etc".

Comment: If you use InnoDB you can use SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to mark the entity as busy.

A good way:  add two columns to the entity's table.

```
    busy_user   INT          either a user id or zero
    busy_until  TIMESTAMP    the time when the busy setting expires, in case the user goes away
```

Then when a user tries to edit an item you do this:

1. if `busy_user` is nonzero and not the current user, and `busy_until > NOW()` reject the request to edit; the item is busy.
2. Set `busy_user` to the current user's id. Set busy_until to `NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`
3. Do the edit as needed.

When a user finishes editing, set `busy_user` to zero.

Comment: In thoery race conditations can still happen with this method